# I never know when to make new classes or what to make classes for when I create a new project, and I struggle with organizing my code

Tags: java, class, code-organization

Whenever I start a new java project I always run into the same problem and never ever seem to learn: I never know what to make classes of, and what to put where. I have a hard time organizing my code into different classes.

For instance, I am currently writing a program for an experiment. It involves spaceships, some enemy spaceships and some friendly spaceships, a gun to shoot at them, and so on. I thought about creating a Spaceship class, but then wasn't sure if that should really be two classes (one for enemy spaceships and one for friendly spaceships). But then I was thinking that it should be one class of which friendly and enemy spaceships could be instances of spaceships. However, the enemy and friendly spaceships serve different purposes throughout the experiment, so maybe not. I also know that I need to create JLabels of these spaceships, and don't know if these should be variables of instances of the Spaceship class or if they should be something that are created in the main method. And this goes on an on.

Does anyone have any tips for instantly knowing how code should be organized, what classes should be made of, and so on? Because this never seems to get any easier for me no matter how many programs I write.

Comment: This question is way too broad for StackOverflow. It's usually something that comes with practice, and having someone who can correct you (like a teacher or a senior colleague). Eventually you develop an intuition for it. The important thing is not to work alone.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question depends on how well you understand object oriented concepts.
As per your requirement you need to make Spaceship interface or super class.   Make enemy spaceship  and friendly spaceship as child class for Spaceship. Similarly you will need to make separate gun class. Depending upon the functionality you need to create object for each. You can make jLabel classes for you spaceships.

Your main method will be in a class which is Entry to your application. You can have different packages depending upon your classes or layers in your application. You should also aware some design pattern before hand for the solution of common problems arising in application development.

Comment: How did you know that I just needed one class for all spaceships and not two, and how did you know I needed a Gun class? How did you make this decision? Also, why do you think I should create a JLabel spaceship class?

Comment: Because Every entity should be an object in Object Oriented Programming. You should consider every thing as an object. And object represents a class. Spaceship with different attribute and behavior should be different object. Or even if they have common attributes/behavior  you should consider polymorphism. This is good practice and the way you should work in Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Could I maybe create a Spaceship class with certain attributes and then have two additional classes, EnemySpaceship and FriendlySpaceship that each extend the Spaceship class? I think this would be a good idea because they share many attributes and behaviors but they also have distinct attributes and behaviors as well.

Comment: Choose my answer as correct. If you feel that helps